# Horror movie/show or scene where a horse creature opens its mouth really wide and devours a man in a stables

Tags: story-identification, horror

I saw my dad watching this when I was a kid and was never really able to identify it later on. At the time it scared the crap out of my little kid brain but now that I'm older I want to find out what he was watching because of how weird the scene I saw was.

From what I can remember, this man was in what looked like horse stables and it was nighttime, and there was this weird looking horse-creature thing in there with him, and its mouth/jaws opened super wide, like way beyond possible wide, and it devours the guy. That's pretty much all I remember because I ran to my room and cried.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It sounds like [The Brothers Grimm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brothers_Grimm_(film)):

The scene below specifically has a boy being eaten by a horse. **NSFW (obviously)**

Comment: That’s a very weird scene

Comment: Thank you! And yeah it is extremely weird

Comment: @CrazyLace Yeah, thanks for the nightmares!

Comment: Possibly a girl, rather than a boy.

Comment: I half-expected the horse to open it's mouth like a Monty Python cutout animation.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I can confirm that, since the plot of  the movie is about kidnapping young girls. This capture is not the scariest/weirdest also :p